# Why Swift Enum generate object, internal variable can't be altered?

Tags: swift

I have an enum that could generate `Some` object, as shown below. However, when I assign the `badgeValue` for the `Some` object, it doesn't store it.

```
class Some {
    public var badgeValue : String = "default"
}

enum MyEnum: Int {
    case x

    var some: Some {
        let some: Some
        switch self {
        case .x:
            some = Some()
        }
        return some
    }
}

let x = MyEnum(rawValue: 0)
x?.some.badgeValue = "New"

print("\(x?.some.badgeValue ?? "Nothing")") // This will print `default`
```

I'm expecting it to print `New`. Why is it print `default` instead? If I instantiate `Some` directly, then the `badgeValue` can be updated. What's so special about the enum store `var` that can't be

Comment: Think about it: Every invocation of `x?.some` creates and returns a *new* instance of `Some`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made your MyEnum var `some` a computed property. A computed property gets evaluated every time you read its value. Thus, every time you invoke `x?.some`, you get a new `Some` object.

As Rob pointed out, my initial suggestion for a way to fix this won't work. Enums can't have stored properites. I think you'll have to use an associated value on your enum case to do what you want.

Comment: Agreed with the problem, but enums can't have stored properties.

Answer (score 0):

Look on you property. It's computed. Every time you create a new instance of Some class.

```
   var some: Some {
            let some: Some
            switch self {
            case .x:
                some = Some()
            }
            return some
        }
```